# Example 9.6 in Loring Tu's An Introduction to manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Example 9.6 is showed as follows in Loring Tu's An Introduction to manifolds:[image]

However, I can't understand the thing that "mainly because". The regular submanifold is defined as follows:
[image]

I don't know what is the relation between "vanishing coordinate functions" and "zero set of coordinate functions". I get confused here, can anyone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it mean that **the inverse image of a regular value is a submanifold**.

About the detail, you can read the do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry or picture below (it also from the do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you disagree with Robert Dixon's answer? I mean, not all submanifolds are preimages of regular values right?

Answer (score 3):

Vanishing is sometimes a synonym for something being zero. The zero set of a function is where the function vanishes/goes to zero. Reading the next line you can see how the adapted chart is just where we have turned all coordinates greater than k to 0, in a sense the information in those higher coordinates has vanished.